# Using Pure HTML, how do you trigger OpenHTMLtoPDF/PDFBox to generate bookmarks or table of contents in the navigation menu?

Tags: java, html, pdfbox, openhtmltopdf

We're trying to add bookmark or table of contents metadata to a PDF that is generated from HTML.
How do you signal PDFBox/OpenHTMLtoPDF to create the bookmarks/TOC?

```
<div class="bkmrk0">Header One</div>
<div class="bkmrk1">Header Two for List</div>
...

<div class="bkmrk2">Header Three Text</div>
...
```

#### Bookmark example on left, TOC on right.

[image: PDF Bookmarks Example]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/site/publish/userguide/bookmarks.html?p=1197837

Comment: I did see that, but that's for manually crating bookmarks. I need something more template driven. (see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Bookmarks:

```
<bookmarks>
 <bookmark name="Font Support" href="#fonts-feature-group"/>
 <bookmark name="RTL &amp; BIDI Text Support" href="#rtl-feature-group"/>
 <bookmark name="Forms Support" href="#forms-feature-group"/>
 <bookmark name="List Support" href="#lists-feature-group"/>
 <bookmark name="Z-Index Support" href="#z-index-feature-group"/>
 <bookmark name="SVG Support (Experimental)" href="#svg-feature-group"/>
</bookmarks>
```

The `href` is the `id` of the element where the bookmark should link to.

https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/blob/14aef95364684fe3c7b7207bcb1246e5c3af0335/openhtmltopdf-examples/src/main/resources/visualtest/html/bookmark-head-nested.html